# What is "mexHttpBinding"?

Tags: wcf

What is "mexHttpBinding" in WCF? When should this binding be used in preference to other bindings?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

It is a binding that returns metadata so you can build a proxy at the client side. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734765.aspx). More [here](https://bloggingabout.net/2006/11/09/wcf-part-4-make-your-service-visible-through-metadata/) as well.

Comment: So are there two endpoints in a WCF service - the standard one and a metadata endpoint?

Comment: You can have any number of endpoints for the same contract, among them mexHttpBinding that provides metadata and in most cases is disabled when in production.

Comment: There can be many different endpoints in a WCF service, with different kinds of bindings and different addresses.

Comment: So metadata endpoints are identified by having an address of "mex"?

Comment: metadata endpoints can have whatever address you give them ("mex", "foo", "bar", etc.) the fact the you assigned them a mex binding is what determines that it's a metadata endpoint

Comment: @CraigS: the Metadata exchange endpoints are those with a contract of `IMetadataExchange` - that's the ultimate deciding factor. It's a system contract that WCF provides for metadata exchange. The address is totally irrelevant, "mex" is just a commonly used best practice, but not a requirement by any means

Answer (score 35):

mexHTTPBinding allows to use [WS-MetadataExchange](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-ws-metadata-exchange-20090317/) over HTTP. You don't need it unless you implemented policies which may change over time and you need to discover your service with UDDI for example

Many people says it's needed for creating client side proxies. This is not true. For client side proxies you need to publish WSDL. You can do that by specifying  in your service behavior.

Shortly, you don't know it -> you don't need it.

Comment: this article says both wsdl and mex are for exchange metadata with client...http://abhishekdv.wordpress.com/2013/05/24/mexhttpbinding-vs-wsdl/ ....

Answer (score 1):

mexHttpBinding is used while adding a new Service Reference in a Project in Visual Studio 2013 (DEBUG) that will consume your WebService (providing the mexHttpBinding). After you've added the Service Reference successfully you might disable the mexHttpBinding.

It is all described in the App.config when you're creating a WCF Service Library Project in the Visual Studio 2013 ( Solution >> Add New Project >> Visual C# >> WCF >> WCF Service Library)