# Creating and Consuming a Webservice entirely within a DLL

Tags: c#, web-services, dll, basichttpbinding

Hope someone here can help me solve this !

I'm writing a custom plugin for Microsoft CRM, which on the creation or update of certain entities, carries out some tasks in the background on our Sharepoint instance, which can't be completed via CRM workflows as they don't have the functionality.

The problem is, that when creating the Service Reference, the defintion for the webservice, with the endpoint address, etc is stored in the DLL's .config file. When deploying the CRM Plugin, the .config file isn't available either when deploying it to disk, or to the database, and the plugin fails as soon as the I try to use the Webservice.

I've had a look at some documentation for BasicHttpBinding, but I'm not entirely sure how I would go about creating the Webservice programmatically, so that it is entirely contained within the DLL.

I'm not bothered about being able to amend the details without recompiling, as the code will be pretty much static anyway.

I've tried defining the Service Reference in the project, as "TestDws"

```
BasicHttpBinding SharepointWS = new BasicHttpBinding();
SharepointWS.Name = "SharepointWebservice";
EndpointAddress EndPoint = new EndpointAddress("http://hostname/_vti_bin/dws.asmx");
TestDws.DwsSoapClient temp = new TestDws.DwsSoapClient(SharepointWS, EndPoint);
```

However, the plugin just craps out at this point.

The original .config doesnt have much more in the way of configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="DwsSoap" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://hostname/_vti_bin/dws.asmx"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="DwsSoap"
                contract="TempDws.DwsSoap" name="DwsSoap" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943148/how-to-programmatically-connect-a-client-to-a-wcf-service http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14012723/configuring-a-wcf-service-binding-in-code http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731862.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I recreated the Service Reference from scratch, and used the same BasicHttpBinding method as above and it worked second time round... albeit now with a HTTP401 on the Sharepoint Webservice !