# WCF IMetadataExchange Error

Tags: wcf, metadata, servicebehavior

I have created a service host with following configuration.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="MathServiceLib.MathService" behaviorConfiguration="myMathServiceBehave">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:9001/MathService"/>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9002/MathService"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:9001/MathService" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="MathServiceLib.IMathService"/>
        <endpoint address ="net.tcp://localhost:9002/MathService" binding ="netTcpBinding" contract="MathServiceLib.IMathService"/>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        <!--<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>-->
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="myMathServiceBehave">
          <!--<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>-->
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I don't want to use serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" property instead I want to use MEX binding for proxy creation.

Now when I start my service using

```
 svcHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(MathServiceLib.MathService));
 svcHost.Open();
```

I get following error, please help.

**The contract name 'IMetadataExchange' could not be found in the list of contracts implemented by the service MathService.  Add a ServiceMetadataBehavior to the configuration file or to the ServiceHost directly to enable support for this contract.**

Comment: Have you implemented the `IMetadataExchange` Interface (as defined in your endpoint)? Or do you just want to introduce another way of connecting to your IMathService? 
Maybe you are missing the `System.ServiceModel.Description` repository?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience, you need to specify

```
<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
```

if you want to use

```
<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
```

The following articles provide comprehensive information and examples:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734765(v=vs.110).aspx
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/81a718/wcf-service-faqs-part-2/

Comment: If we specify httpGetEnabled=true, then what the significance of mexHttpBinding endpoint?

Comment: The following StackOverflow Q/A may help provide some insight ...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106637/what-is-mexhttpbinding ... regards