# adding a service reference to net.msmq wcf service

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm trying to add a service reference to my wcf app in visual studio.
I can do it for various bindings such as net.pipe and basichttp...
but to net.msmq binding, I get error

Here is the relevant part of my web.config:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <netMsmqBinding>
        <binding name="netMsmqBinding" exactlyOnce="false">
          <security mode="None"></security>
        </binding>
      </netMsmqBinding>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basicHttp" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WCF_ServiceSample.WCF_ServiceBehavior" />
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="serviceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata />
          <serviceDebug />
          <serviceDiscovery />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehavior" name="WCF_ServiceSample.WCF_Service">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:4000/Services/" />
            <add baseAddress="net.msmq://localhost/Services/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>

        <endpoint address="mex" behaviorConfiguration="WCF_ServiceSample.WCF_ServiceBehavior"
          binding="mexHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" name="mex_http"
          contract="IMetadataExchange" />

        <endpoint address="AdventureWorksServiceHttp" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          name="basicHttpEndpt" contract="WCF_ServiceSample.WCF_Service" />

        <endpoint address="AdventureWorksServiceNetMsmq"
          binding="netMsmqBinding" bindingConfiguration="netMsmqBinding"
          contract="WCF_ServiceSample.WCF_Service" />

      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Here is the error I get when I run my service via the wcf client:

> Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from
>   http://localhost:9011/WCF_Service.svc If this is a Windows (R)
>   Communication Foundation service to which you have access, please
>   check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the specified
>   address. For help enabling metadata publishing, please refer to the
>   MSDN documentation at
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65455.WS-Metadata Exchange
>   Error URI: http://localhost:9011/WCF_Service.svc Metadata contains a
>   reference that cannot be resolved:
>   'http://localhost:9011/WCF_Service.svc'. The server did not provide a
>   meaningful reply; this might be caused by a contract mismatch, a
>   premature session shutdown or an internal server error.HTTP GET Error
>   URI: http://localhost:9011/WCF_Service.svc There was an error
>   downloading 'http://localhost:9011/WCF_Service.svc'. The request
>
> ### failed with the error message:--  Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Could not find a base address that matches scheme net.msmq for the
>   endpoint with binding NetMsmqBinding. Registered base address schemes
>   are [http].  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the
>   execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace
>   for more information about the error and where it originated in the
>   code.

here is the error I get when I go to add service reference ->
net.msmq://localhost/WCF_Service.svc
then I press "Go"

> The URI prefix is not recognized. The MetadataExchangeClient instance
>   could not be initialized because no Binding is available for scheme
>   'net.msmq'. You can supply a Binding in the constructor, or specify a
>   configurationName. Parameter name: scheme If the service is defined in
>   the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service
>   reference again.

Answer (score 1):

add mex bindings as that will allow you to add proxy reference, then you can use the net.msmq bindings to do the operation.

[What is "mexHttpBinding"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106637/what-is-mexhttpbinding)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa967390(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I've tried that. It did not work. I'm guessing that what you mean is to use mex and add a reference on the http end point instead of trying to add a reference to the net.msmq. I've tried that and I get an error that says "An error occurred while opening the queue:The queue does not exist or you do not have sufficient permissions to perform the operation." I've tried running visual studio as admin and made sure msmq is installed.

Comment: yes, that's what i meant. now your error message is different, it is saying you don't have permission to talk to MSMQ. you will need to make sure application pool user has permission on MSMQ.